# How to register ASP.NET 2.0 to web server(IIS7)?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net-2.0

I have a web-page application already created, but when I open it in visual studio 2008, it says there that:

ASP.NET 2.0 has not been registered on the Web Server. You need to
   manually configure you Web server for ASP.NET 2.0 in order for your
   site to run correctly.

I'm using asp.net 2.0, IIS7 and running on vista home premium.

How to register ASP.NET 2.0 to my web server(IIS7)?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**ASP .NET 2.0:**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

**ASP .NET 4.0:**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Run Command Prompt as Administrator to avoid the `...requested operation requires elevation` error

---

`aspnet_regiis.exe` should no longer be used with **IIS7** to install **ASP.NET**

1. Open Control Panel
2. Programs\Turn Windows Features on or off
3. Internet Information Services
4. World Wide Web Services
5. Application development Features
6. **ASP.Net** <== check mark here

Comment: That worked with IIS 5, but is it adequate with IIS 7? Does it enable all of the features that will be necessary? They're disabled by default in IIS 7.

Comment: there is an error when i did that. it says that:
   "An error has occured: 0x800702e4 the requested operation requires
    elevation."

Comment: Darin, sorry for re-opening this problem again, but I have the same problem here and while trying to follow your suggestion I've figured out that I have no WWW services -> Application development Features available anywhere.... 
any chance to provide the full paths again and possibly a bit more detailed?
[Windows Server 2007 / IIS7 ]

thanks!

Comment: mea culpa... found it.. I was temporarily blinded : )

Comment: If using Windows 7, run Command Prompt as Administrator to avoid "... the requested operation requires elevation" error.

Comment: This still works to fix the same exact issue on MS VS 2010, if anyone's wondering. Cheers Darin !!

Answer (score 10):

If anyone like me is still unable to register ASP.NET with IIS.

You just need to run these three commands one by one in command prompt

> cd c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727

after that, Run

> aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable

and Finally Reset IIS

> iisreset

Hope it helps the person in need... cheers!

Answer (score 8):

If you installed IIS after the .Net framework you can solve the porblem by re-installing the .Net framework. Part of its install detects whether IIS is present and updates IIS accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, @sipwiz, I can stop banging my head on my desk now.  Microsoft, please go jump in a lake.

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel
- Programs
- Turn Windows Features on or off
expand - Internet Information Services
expand - World Wide Web Services
expand - Application development Features
check -  ASP.Net

Its advisable you check other feature to avoid future problem that might not give direct error messages
Please don't forget to mark this question as answered if it solves your problem for the purpose of others

Answer (score 1):

The system I was working on is Windows Server 2008 Standard with IIS 7 (I guess that my experience will apply for all Windows systems of the same age).

Running

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

SEEMED to work, as

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -lv
```

showed the .Net framework v4 registered with IIS.

But, running the same for .Net v2, namely

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

did NOT result in

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -lv
```

showing the framework registered.

(And, for me, the installer for Kofax Capture Network Server was still missing ASP.NET.)

The solution was:

- Open Server Manager
- Go to Roles/Web Server (IIS)
- Push Add Role Services
- check ASP.NET under Application Development (and press Install)

After that, aspnet_regiis.exe -lv (either version) shows the framework registered.
(And the Kofax installer was also happy and worked.)

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by doing Repir  on .NET framework Extended, in  Add/Remove program ;

Using win2008R2, .NET framework 4.0