# Session("xxxx") is always Nothing in InitializeCulture Method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application in VB.NET. Recently I have upgraded its .net framework to 4.6.1.

In one of the pages, Session values are being read in an InitializeCulture method.
Note that those values are set in other pages from where redirection has happened to this page.

It works fine when I run the application from Visual Studio 2017, however when deployed to IIS with app pool of 4.0 classic , the session values are always considered as Nothing and control goes inside If block.

I also tried the solution given in [Can't use Session in InitializeCulture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520272/cant-use-session-in-initializeculture) but it is not working.

What may be the issue?

```
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
   'Below condition is always true
    If (Session("Country") Is Nothing) Or (Session("ID") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx")
    End If       

End Sub
```

Comment: Are those Session values still Nothing in "OtherPage.aspx"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes.Session values still Nothing in "OtherPage.aspx"

Comment: Is the site meant to be using https? [Losing session data in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871081/losing-session-data-in-asp-net).