# IIS7 only able to load Default Web Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to set up IIS to run websites instead of running them on VS Development Server. I've registered ASP.NET with IIS correctly (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647598/how-to-register-asp-net-2-0-to-web-serveriis7) to make sure), added a new site with the correct physical path, binded an address (site1.com) and added it to the hosts file, but it's not working: it just shows that it's loading endlessly in Firefox.

I'm able to ping site1.com and I get a reply. I'm also able to load `http://localhost/` and it shows the default IIS page. What could I be missing?

**edit:** I've also checked "Use Local IIS Web server" in my project properties

Comment: Did you map site1.com to your local ip address so that dns resolves it to your iis?

Comment: Yup. '127.0.0.1 site1.com' in hosts file.

Comment: What if you put test.html there and navigate to site1.com/test.html so that no asp.net is involved?

Comment: Hah, interesting suggestion. Same problem.

Comment: My guess is that you have something wrong in your /etc/hosts. This is because site1.com also loads forever for me but in contrast to you I don't have it mapped to anything locally and my browser just uses a default, globally resolved ip. I believe your browser does the same. Check the local mapping, restart the browser and check if ping reaches 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Pinging site1.com gives me a reply from 127.0.0.1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the issue was multiple versions of IIS on one machine. After formatting the machine, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I assume you have 2 sites running (1_Default web site, 2_Site1.com) on your IIS.

Suggest solution : 
 Try to stop your default website and load site1.com in your browser.

Go to site1.com > Right click  go to Edit Bindings and set the port number to be 80.
try going to site1.com.

Cheers

Comment: The port is 80. I tried stopping Default site but still the same problem - endlessly loading.

Comment: If you can let us know more about your application, You can help us help you. for eg. Does it run successfully when you build or run from your visual studio? DB Connections ? Go to IIS Default document > Suggest any page. try using another browser. try iisreset. Have you set your application pool ?? try http://forums.iis.net/t/1187161.aspx/1

Comment: Runs fine from VS Dev Server. DB connection isn't the issue because it won't even resolve a static html page. I've tried resetting IIS, and I've set application pool to use .NET v4.0 with integrated pipeline