# Signalr client side functions not being called when hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, iis-7, websocket, signalr

I have a signal r application that is working in visual studio, locally, but when I publish to IIS 7 in my local machine, it runs fine. but my signal client callback functions, ain't receiving any calls from the hub class on the server.

I don't know what are the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Web Sockets in the machine.

To enable support for the WebSocket Protocol on Windows Server 2012, use the following steps:

1. Open **Server Manager**.
2. Under the **Manage** menu, click **Add Roles and Features**.
3. Select **Role-based or Feature-based Installation**, and then click **Next**.
4. Select the appropriate server, (your local server is selected by default), and then click **Next**.
5. Expand **Web Server (IIS)** in the **Roles** tree, then expand **Web Server**, and then expand **Application Development**.
6. Select **WebSocket Protocol**, and then click **Next**.
7. If no additional features are needed, click **Next**.
8. Click **Install**.
9. When the installation completes, click **Close** to exit the wizard.

When the installation completes, click Close to exit the wizard.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

**Windows 8 :**

1. Click the Windows button
2. Type: Turn windows features on or off
3. Navigate to: Internet Information Services > World Wide Web services > Application Development Features
4. Select “Websocket Protocol” + OK

Comment: Because I'm  using windows 8, I had to turn on IIS WebSocket Protocol feature. However this hasn't work. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/programming-html5-web-sockets-in-asp.net-4.5.htm

Comment: Try registering the asp.net with iis .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/647609/2074346

Comment: Signalr should fall back to non-websockets transports if they aren't available, I believe. I.e. from the [Introduction to SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr): "SignalR uses the new WebSocket transport where available, and falls back to older transports where necessary"

Comment: I'm running .net4.5, and this is turned on, IIS in windows Features

Comment: I've included this line of code, but still no luck. connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] })